# WebRTC GainNode not working on iOS (iPhone)

Tags: javascript, webrtc, web-audio-api, simplewebrtc

### The Aim

- Change the gain (microphone volume) on the live stream.
- In the demo, you will be able to change from a low gain (0.1) to a high gain (1). When it is set to 0.1, you will hardly hear yourself, it's like a whisper mode.

### The Problem

The code below works on Windows, Android and Safari desktop version, but when I tried running it in Safari on my iPhone SE, I'm not hearing a whisper or low gain. I checked the value of the gain node and it was set to 0.1 when I clicked the button, but it seems like it didn't take effect.

### Link to the demo:

https://unrupt.github.io/webrtc-samples/stream-gain-control.html

### Safari Media Supported Constraints on the iPhone

- aspectRatio
- deviceId
- echoCancellation
- facingMode
- frameRate
- groupId
- height
- samepleRate
- sampleSize
- volume
- width

### Code:

```
    <h2 class="w3-center">Media Stream with Gain Control</h2>
    <p class="w3-center">The aim of this sample is to control the gain of the stream</p>
    <audio id="audio" playsinline="true" controls autoplay></audio><br>
    <button class="btn-fn" onclick="start()">Start!</button>
    <button class="btn-fn" onclick="updateGain(0.001)">Low Gain</button>
    <button class="btn-fn" onclick="updateGain(1)">Default Gain</button>
    <script>
        var AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;

        var localStream;
        var gainNode;
        var ctx;
        var dst;
        var start = () => navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true})
          .then(stream => audio.srcObject = modifyGain(stream, 2.5))
          .catch(e => log(e));

        var modifyGain = (stream, gainValue) => {
            localStream = stream;
          ctx = new AudioContext();
          var src = ctx.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
          dst = ctx.createMediaStreamDestination();
          gainNode = ctx.createGain();
          gainNode.gain.value = gainValue;
          src.connect(gainNode);
          gainNode.connect(dst);
          outputStream = dst.stream;
          stream.addTrack(outputStream.getAudioTracks()[0]);
          stream.removeTrack(stream.getAudioTracks()[0]);
          //[src, gainNode, dst].reduce((a, b) => a && a.connect(b));
          return stream;
        };

        var updateGain = (value) => {
          gainNode.gain.value = value;
        };

        var log = msg => div.innerHTML += "<br>" + msg;
    </script>
```

**Any suggestions to what I could try?**

Comment: Safari still prefixes its AudioContext constructor (`ctx = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();`)

Comment: Yea, I have that in the code. It's still not working.

Comment: I updated the description for the issue

Comment: Indeed they seem to have issues with MediaStreamDestinationNode's MediaStream: https://github.com/webrtc/samples/issues/925#issuecomment-357033903 (by an user which seems to be involved in webkit dev). This [can be reproduced with a simple oscillator](https://jsfiddle.net/thj674zc/) and makes me wonder why they do even have this method if it's of no use... For your case, do you really need to output a MediaStream? Couldn't you simply do all on the audioContext's destination rather than going through the <audio>?

Comment: Yes, I could have and I think that would work. However, I plan to use the code in RTCPeerConnection, whereby I want to adjust the gain or edit the stream before sending it to the remote user.

Comment: Here is a [bug report](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=173863) about this exact issue. Unfortunately, it doesn't say if it works when passed through RTC channels, or if it is only a problem with MediaElements and I couldn't test it myself either. If it doesn't, you should consider Safari as not supporting createMediaStreamDestination, and maybe apply a fallback to AudioContext.destination, or simply setting the volume of your output `<audio>` (since they don't support MediaElement.captureStream() either, we can't create such a MediaStream on this UA...)